# OpenCL sum `cl_khr_fp64` double values into a single number

Tags: opencl, reduction

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037111/opencl-using-atomic-reduction-for-double) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139314/double-sum-reduction-opencl-tutorial) I managed to compile a minimal example of summing a vector into a single double inside OpenCL 1.2.

```c
    /* https://suhorukov.blogspot.com/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html */
    inline void AtomicAdd(volatile __global double *source, const double operand) {
      union { unsigned int intVal; double floatVal; } prevVal, newVal;
      do {
        prevVal.floatVal = *source;
        newVal.floatVal = prevVal.floatVal + operand;
      } while( atomic_cmpxchg((volatile __global unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != prevVal.intVal );
    }

    void kernel cost_function(__constant double* inputs, __global double* outputs){
      int index = get_global_id(0);

      if(0 == error_index){ outputs[0] = 0.0; }
      barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

      AtomicAdd(&outputs[0], inputs[index]); /* (1) */
      //AtomicAdd(&outputs[0], 5.0); /* (2) */

    }
```

As in fact this solution is incorrect because the result is always 0 when the buffer is accessed. What might the problem with this?

the code at `/* (1) */` doesn't work, and neither does the code at `/* (2) */`, which is only there to test the logic independent of any inputs.

Is `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);` used correctly here to reset the output before any calculations are done to it?

According to [the specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) in OpenCL 1.2 single precision floating point numbers are supported by atomic operations, is this(`AtomicAdd`) a feasible method of extending the support to double precision numbers or am I missing something?

Of course the device I am testing with supports `cl_khr_fp64`˙of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AtomicAdd` is incorrect. Namely, the 2 errors are:

1. In the `union`, `intVal` must be a 64-bit integer and not 32-bit integer.
2. Use the 64-bit [`atom_cmpxchg`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atom_cmpxchg.html) function and not the 32-bit [`atomic_cmpxchg`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_cmpxchg.html) function.

The correct implementation is:

```c
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable
inline void AtomicAdd(volatile __global double *source, const double operand) {
    union { unsigned ulong u64; double f64; } prevVal, newVal;
    do {
        prevVal.f64 = *source;
        newVal.f64 = prevVal.f64 + operand;
    } while(atom_cmpxchg((volatile __global ulong*)source, prevVal.u64, newVal.u64) != prevVal.u64);
}
```

`barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);` is used correctly here. Note that a `barrier` must not be in an `if`- or `else`-branch.

UPDATE: According to [STREAMHPC](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2016-02-09/atomic-operations-for-floats-in-opencl-improved/), the original implementation you use is not guaranteed to produce correct results. There is an improved implementation:

```c
void __attribute__((always_inline)) atomic_add_f(volatile global float* addr, const float val) {
    union {
        uint  u32;
        float f32;
    } next, expected, current;
    current.f32 = *addr;
    do {
        next.f32 = (expected.f32=current.f32)+val; // ...*val for atomic_mul_f()
        current.u32 = atomic_cmpxchg((volatile global uint*)addr, expected.u32, next.u32);
    } while(current.u32!=expected.u32);
}

#ifdef cl_khr_int64_base_atomics
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable
void __attribute__((always_inline)) atomic_add_d(volatile global double* addr, const double val) {
    union {
        ulong  u64;
        double f64;
    } next, expected, current;
    current.f64 = *addr;
    do {
        next.f64 = (expected.f64=current.f64)+val; // ...*val for atomic_mul_d()
        current.u64 = atom_cmpxchg((volatile global ulong*)addr, expected.u64, next.u64);
    } while(current.u64!=expected.u64);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Awesome! Meanwhile I figured it out as well! Although it only works if the cast is to `volatile __global ulong`. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: and the following needs to be set: `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics: enable` If you extend your answer with this information I will acept it; and thank you!

Comment: Correct! I missed those 2 things.

Comment: @David Tóth please see my uptated answer again: There is an improved implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: According to the post `atomic_cmpxchg` needs to be used, but that was used originally as well...  I think I am missing the logical  changes between the two versions of kernel code; To be more precise, I don't see what is guaranteeing that the result will not be. According to the specs, the only difference is that `atom_cmpxchg` is for 64 bit numbers, and `atomic_cmpxchg` is for 32 bits..

Comment: AH! Nevermind  I think I got it: the return value of the function is not correct, but the memory load of the current is.