# Local memory using C++ Wrappers

Tags: opencl

I wish to use local work groups for my kernels, but I'm having some issues passing the 'NULL' parameters to my kernels. I hope to know how to pass these parameters using the methods that I'm using which I will show below, as opposed to setArg which I saw here: [How to declare local memory in OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888718/how-to-declare-local-memory-in-opencl)

I have the following host code for my kernel:

*initialized in a .h file*:

```
std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>> setInputKernel;
```

*in host code*:

```
this->setInputKernel.reset(new cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>(program, "setInputs"));
```

*enqueue kernel code*:

```
(*setInputKernel)(cl::EnqueueArgs(*queue, cl::NDRange(1000),cl::NDRange(1000)),
            cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer);
```

*kernel code*:

```
kernel void setInputs(global float* restrict inputArr, global float* restrict inputs)
```

I have already set the appropriate sizes and setting for my local work group parameters. However, I did not successfully pass the data into the kernel.

The kernel with the local work group updates:

```
kernel void setInputs(global float* restrict inputArr, global float*
                      restrict inputs, local float* inputArrLoc, local float* inputsLoc)
```

I had tried to change my code accordingly by using NULL or cl::Buffer for the input params of the kernels, but didn't work:

```
std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, NULL, NULL>> setInputKernel;
std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>> setInputKernel;
```

with the first attempt giving me compiler issues saying that the function expects a value while I did not give one, and the second attempt returning clSetKernelArg error when I try to run the kernel. In both examples, I had ensured that all the parameters for the headers and host files were consistent.

I also tried to just put NULL behind my cl::Buffers when I enqueue the kernel, but this returns an error telling me that there is no function for call.

How do I pass parameters to my kernel in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `LocalSpaceArg` type and `Local` helper function to do this.

The type of your kernel would be this:

```
cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::LocalSpaceArg, cl::LocalSpaceArg>
```

You would then specify the size of the local memory allocations when you enqueue the kernel by using `cl::Local(size)` (where `size` is the number of bytes you wish to allocate).

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use `cl::Local`, does this mean that my ocl version does not support this yet?

‘Local’ is not a member of ‘cl’

Comment: Update: it seems my library was missing a few lines.

Added this:


/*! Local
 * \brief Helper function for generating LocalSpaceArg objects.
 */
inline LocalSpaceArg
Local(::size_t size)
{
    LocalSpaceArg ret = { size };
    return ret;
}

from the cl.hpp file from Khronos and it worked.