# Create local array dynamic inside OpenCL kernel

Tags: memory-management, opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl

I have a OpenCL kernel that needs to process a array as multiple arrays where each sub-array sum is saved in a local cache array.

For example, imagine the fowling array:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 30, 1, 23]]
```

- Each work-group gets a array (in the exemple we have 2 work-groups);
- Each work-item process two array indexes (for example multiply the value index the local_id), where the work-item result is saved in a work-group shared array.

  ```
  __kernel void test(__global int **values, __global int *result, const int array_size){
      __local int cache[array_size];

      // initialise
      if (get_local_id(0) == 0){
          for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
              cache[i] = 0;
      }

      barrier (CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

      if(get_global_id(0) < 4){
          for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
              cache[get_local_id(0)] += values[get_group_id(0)][i] * 
                                                           get_local_id(0);
      }

      barrier (CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

      if(get_local_id(0) == 0){
          for (int i = 0; i<array_size; i++)
              result[get_group_id(0)] += cache[i];
      }
  }
  ```

The problem is that I can not define the cache array size by using a kernel parameter, but i need to in order to have a dynamic kernel.

How can I create it dynamically? like malloc function in c...

Or the only solution available is to send a temp array to my kernel function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541929/how-do-i-use-local-memory-in-opencl

Answer (score 18):

This can be achieved by adding `__local` array as a kernel parameter:

```
__kernel void test(__global int **values, __global int *result, 
    const int array_size, __local int * cache)
```

and providing desired size of the kernel parameter:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, array_size*sizeof(int), NULL);
```

The local memory will be allocated upon the kernel invocation. Note, that extra checks may be necessary to ensure that required local memory size does not exceed the device limit.