# How is opencl local memory transformed?

Tags: opencl, global, local

I have a simple opencl code like that:

```
__kernel void cache(
    __global float* data,
    __local float* sharedData) 
{
    int globalId=get_global_id(0);

    int localId=get_local_id(0);

    // Cache data to local memory
    sharedData[localId]=data[globalId];
}
```

There are two input memory, one is global one is local.

For example, the global size I applied is {10000},
and the local size is {10}

So this "int globalId=get_global_id(0);" will get a number between 0~9999 right?
"int localId=get_local_id(0);" will get a number like: "0~9"

Then how does this "sharedData[localId]=data[globalId];" Copy the data from global to local?
Will we have 10000* 10's situations?
like:

```
sharedData[0]=data[0];
sharedData[0]=data[1];
sharedData[0]=data[2];
...
sharedData[1]=data[0];
sharedData[1]=data[1];
...
```

So, what's going on about sharedData[localId]=data[globalId];

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes more like this (conceptually):

```
sharedData[get_group_id(0) returns 0][0]=data[0];
sharedData[get_group_id(0) returns 0][1]=data[1];
sharedData[get_group_id(0) returns 0][2]=data[2];
...
sharedData[get_group_id(0) returns 1][0]=data[10];
sharedData[get_group_id(0) returns 1][1]=data[11];
sharedData[get_group_id(0) returns 1][2]=data[12];
...
```

You can imagine that the local memory is 2d array implicitly indexed by the workgroup id. Naturally you cannot access the local memory of a different group from another group. But it can help you to understand the concept.

So there will just be 10000 reads split into groups of 10.

Answer (score 1):

As kernel code is executed by all Work Items, number of operations is equal to NDSize of your kernel. So, total number of readings will be 10000.

Then, as `get_local_id(0)` returns only 10 different values (size of Work Group is equal to 10), number of local arrays will be 10000 / 10 = 1000.

You are reading different data from global memory by unique WI ID (`get_global_id()` always return unique number for every Work Item), no data duplication will take place.

Finally, your code will dice up a 10000 global array into 1000 local arrays, each of size 10,

Answer (score 1):

There is a decent example here:

[How do I use local memory in OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541929/how-do-i-use-local-memory-in-opencl)

https://github.com/lettergram/Cache-Comparison/blob/master/cl/opencl.h

Local data is only usable inside the kernel and cannot be returned. The global data is actually returned upon execution.